# debug do vs code para c++ nao abre o console para entrada de dados durante o programa

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debug

configurei o debug para depurar o codigo em c++, mas ao iniciar o debug nenhum console é aberta para que eu possa dar entrada de valores. Ja reconfigurei o launch.json dessa forma:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Iniciar",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar a reformatação automática para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Definir Tipo de Desmontagem como Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

ainda assim não funciona,
conforme foi pedido vou postar o código que estou tentando depurar:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter 10 number in sequence: " << endl;
    int size = 10;
    float A[size];
    float sum = 0;

    float min = 999999; // limites numérico do float std::max
    float max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
        sum += A[i];

        if (A[i] < min)
            min = A[i];
        if (A[i] > max)
            max = A[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Avg is " << sum / size << endl;
    cout << "Min is " << min << " and Max is " << max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: poste o código que você está tentando compilar .

Comment: pronto, editei a postagem e coloquei o código abaixo

Comment: Olhando o arquivo de configuração me chamou a atenção o depurador estar configurado para depurar o arquivo `a.exe`, veja se esse arquivo existe.

Comment: Siga o passo a passo da documentação oficial, provavelmente você pulou alguma das etapas: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: o a.exe é o arquivo criando pelo launch.json para executar a depuração. Quando eu rodo o debug ele analisa as variáveis normalmente, a única diferença é que nao mostra no terminal nem as saídas que eu dou através do cout e nem possibilita entradas pelo cin

Comment: Algum motivo em especial pra estar configurado para console externo? Se bem que não quero encompridar o assunto aqui, o ideal é [edit] a pergunta e apresentar algo que seja possível a comunidade reproduzir sem chutes, o mais próximo possível da documentação oficial (e o que mudar disso, ter como certificar que não é o problema). Comentários são pra esclarecimentos imediatos e pontuais, mas não suprem a necessidade de a pergunta ser autosuficiente e útil como referência canônica para outros programadores. Ainda, se for ver, o [su] é o site de suporte da rede, a [help] detalhe melhor esse aqui.